# Angular, watch a variable update via AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a cart controller, that manages cart in e-store. Ordered products are stored in `scope.cart`. In view I have buttons to change item's cnt, like `<elem ng-click="inc(c)" />`, so inc function incrementing `c.cnt`

Now, I want to watch cart object, so on cnt change I can make XHR call to change data in user session. That's ok and working fine, the problem is I have some difficult pricing rules, so I have to return prices manually within same XHR query, and update `scope.cart`. This makes a loop, and I wonder how do I make things proper, angular-way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to watch the cart object changes if you have a `function` that increments the cart items.

i.e

```
$scope.inc = function(c) {
  // Do your cart logic here and then
  $http({method: "PUT", url: "/cart"})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       // update cart object with new pricing rules
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       // handle errors
    });
};
```